# Remove buttons added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding extra selects and text fields to a form using jQuery. However I want to be able to remove added text fields using the remove button.

Once a field has been added jQuery can not seem to detect it.

jQuery

```
var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {


    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
        .attr("id", 'contact-list-div-' + counter).attr("class", 'contact-list-div');

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select></select>' +
    '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
    '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >' + '<button type="button" class="removeButton" id="removeButton-' + counter + '">Remove Button</button>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#contact-list");


    counter++;
});


$(".removeButton").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); //this never shows, only on the element that was 
                    //added directly added using html, in this case removeButton-1
});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="contact-list">
            <div class="contact-list-div" id="contact-list-div-1">
                <select></select>
                <input>
                <button type='button' class='removeButton' id='removeButton-1'>Remove Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event-[delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeButton',function() {
    $(this).parents('.contact-list-div').remove();                     
});
```

You appending content to your DOM **after the event-listener for your click on `.removeButton` is registered**. So this element does not exist at the time your binding a click event to it.

Through event-delegation you are able to bind an event-listiner to an **existing parent** (`document` in this case, **but `#contact-list` would be working too**). And this will listen to all events of its descendants matching the `.removeButton` - selector.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/56gfos6k/1/)

Comment: Please add a little snippet about **why** event-delegation works.

Comment: @krillgar I added a little explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#contact-list').on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
    //Your code                        
});
```

Comment: @devqon answered some seconds before me

Comment: actually more than one answered before me :)

Comment: Voted up, because it's better to use event delegation on a closest parent with an `id`, than `body` or `document`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are binding the events to elements that do not yet exist.

Use jQuery delegation to enable handlers on not yet existing elements:

```
$("body").on("click", ".removeButton", function() {
    alert(this.id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the click listener only at the first button.
Try using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(document).delegate(".removeButton", "click", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

This tells the document that whenever a event click occours on an element with class "removeButton" it should call that callback

(You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7suo17L6/1/))

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is dynamicly added with jQuery, the normal `.click` event of jQuery will be not able to detect the new added elements.

Use instead `.on`. See the example below:

```
$("body").on("click", ".removeButton", function() {
    alert(this.id); //this never shows, only on the element that was 
                    //added directly added using html, in this case removeButton-1
});
```